# Open file in chosen application in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, notepad++

I would like to open a file using the cmdln in PowerShell with a particular application.

In my case, I have a file `scripts.js` which I'd like to open in `Notepad++` but which would normally open in regular `notepad.exe` if I did this: `Invoke-Item .\scripts.js`

What should I do to open that file in `Notepad++`?

Answer (score 25):

By using **Start-Process** you can do:

```
$FileLocation = 'C:\temp\test\scripts.js'
Start-Process notepad++ $FileLocation
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the [call operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) and pass the file as an argument to the program you want to open it with:

```
& 'C:\path\to\notepad++.exe' '.\script.js'
```