# Powershell - Correct file path defined, but Start-Process tries to navigate from application location

Tags: powershell, start-process

I saw this answer below, and had implemented something similar. However, whenever I start Notepad++ I receive an error that the file cannot be opened due to that file not existing. I will point out I am attempting to do this from the Root of C. Error:

Link to answer in question:
[Open file in chosen application in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669962/open-file-in-chosen-application-in-powershell/42670175)

[image: Error example pointing to the wrong file path]

My little snippet is as follows:

```
$abcFilePath = "C:Test\abc-webservices\$ClientName\abc.xml"
$Openabc = Start-Process notepad++ "C:Test\abc-webservices\$ClientName\abc.xml"
```

"TestCase" in the error is $ClientName from above. However based on the link I provided, should this not open up the correct file? Why is it attempting to navigate to the file from the folder Notepad++ is located in. Am I missing a step?

Comment: I have the path typed out in $Openabc because i was testing to see if it was my variable causing the problems. But when I call the variable in Powershell it does indeed list the file path I am expecting.

Comment: Can you try “C:\Test...” instead of “C:Test” in your paths? Without the backslash, the path is being calculated relative to the “current directory” on the C drive, which in your case is the folder that notepad++ is installed in.

Comment: Thank you. That was it. This is why I like working with people. Catch my simple mistakes. I appreciate your assistance.